# How to pass multiple parameters for SOAP function using Zeep?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, zeep

I am accessing a Web Service using Zeep. From the wsdl of the web service, there are multiple functions/operations. All of them they take "strings" as inputs. I was able to access and get outputs from all the functions using the code below:

```
from zeep import Client
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password')

wsdl = "https://website.asmx?wsdl"
client=Client(wsdl,transport=Transport(session=session))

y=client.service.Function('string input')
```

The code above will output results from the web service since it has only one string input.
However, I have another function in the wsdl that has multiple inputs. I know that wehn you have multiple inputs you combine them all in a dictionary `request_data={'param1' : 'string1','param2': 'string2'}`. However, on of the inputs in this function is a Query, which takes multiple strings as input. The strings are basically titles of a a table in the webservice, and I can call out te data from this table by calling the column titles. However, I don't know how to combine all of these strings in one input. The XML format for these strings in the SOAP message is like below:

```
<Query xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt; xmlns="link" version="version number"&gt;
  &lt;string1=""&gt;
    &lt;string2 /&gt;
    &lt;string3 /&gt;
    &lt;string4&gt;
      &lt;string5 /&gt;
    &lt;/string6&gt;
    &lt;string7/&gt;
    &lt;string8&gt;
      &lt;string9 /&gt;
      &lt;string10 /&gt;
      &lt;string11 /&gt;
    &lt;/string12&gt;
  &lt;/string13&gt;
&lt;/string14&gt;</Query>
```

How do I convert this XML SOAP input so that it is accepted by Zeep as an input?

I tried combining all of the strings in the dictionary like below using XML format in python

```
request_data={'Query':'&lt; xmlns="link" version="version number"&gt;
  &lt;string1=""&gt;
    &lt;string2 /&gt;
    &lt;string3 /&gt;
    &lt;string4&gt;
      &lt;string5 /&gt;
    &lt;/string6&gt;
    &lt;string7/&gt;
    &lt;string8&gt;
      &lt;string9 /&gt;
      &lt;string10 /&gt;
      &lt;string11 /&gt;
    &lt;/string12&gt;
  &lt;/string13&gt;
&lt;/string14&gt;'}
```

However, I get the following error: Function_Name(Inspect number of queries)Root element is missing.

Comment: The `&lt;` is an open angle bracket and `&gt` is a closing angle bracket.  You are sending xml data and the root tag is the Query.  You wrapped all the xml data except the Query tags with angle brackets.  You need to do the same with Query.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. However, forgive me but I don't understand what you meant! Do you mean that I should use the angle brackets for all of these strings. Will python recognize this formatting? Or I have to include all of them in a dictionary?

Comment: You are sending an HTTP request which is HTML format.  Angle brackets are special character that MAY need escaping like `&lt;` and 1&gt;`.  I do not know enough about zeep on how it handles SOAP.  Normally with a HTTP request you indicate the content type as XML and then you do not need to escape the angle brackets.  All the angle brackets in your case should be handled the same.  Either ESCAPE or do not ESCAPE (not sure which way works with zeep).  You have combination of some angle brackets being ESCAPED and others not.

Comment: I made all the strings in XML format with brackets and defined as a string, then called it inside of the Zeep function and it worked perfectly